How do we manage sessions with reactJs, OAuth2.0 and spring boot?
I am building a web and mobile app with react/react native for front end, Java-spring boot for backend with OAuth2 authorization.
Google OAuth Login from the react web app works fine. How do I manage login sessions and invalidate them on logout.
Any suggestions/advice will be helpful.
Thanks in advance.
Haven't really tried anything  yet; want to understand how this needs to be done so I can check for the same on the mobile app as well.

I found similar question already asked
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75784963/spring-boot-oauth-client-authorization-server-react-implementation
However, in below answer I tried add logout endpoint

It would be a bad experience for users to be disconnected from Google when they log out from your app. But if their Google session remains active after their session on your app is ended, then their next "login with Google" from your app will run silently (this is just what SSO is about) and they'll feel like they never logged out from your app.
A solution is to use an authorization server of your own in front of Google. Almost all OIDC Providers implement "Login with ...". In such a configuration, you can end the session on your authorization server without ending the social login provider session. Also, this will have several side benefits like enabling you to manage user data (add stuff like roles).
I wrote a tutorial for getting started with Spring & Keycloak on Baeldung.
I wrote another tutorial about the OAuth2 BFF pattern for single-page applications. It covers React web apps.
In this other answer, I detailed what it takes to authorize requests with sessions (and CSRF token) from a mobile app.

Noted. I will check the links you have provided. Thank you @ch4mp

Reference to spring security

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session
https://www.baeldung.com/logout-spring-security-oauth

Here I am trying to post skeleton that can be improved upon as per your project requirements.
Spring Security Config
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
            .loginPage("/oauth2/authorization/google")
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user")
            .password("{noop}password")
            .roles("USER");
    }
}



RestController to expose login/logout endpoints
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {

    @PostMapping("/logout")
    public ResponseEntity<?> logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null) {
            new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new LogoutResponse("Logout successful"));
    }

    public static class LogoutResponse {
        private String message;

        public LogoutResponse(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
    }
}


properties file
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id=your-client-id
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret=your-client-secret
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.redirect-uri={baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/google
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.scope=openid,profile,email
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.google.authorization-uri=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.google.token-uri=https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.google.user-info-uri=https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.google.jwk-set-uri=https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs


React Logout component
const Logout = () => {
    const handleLogout = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post('/auth/logout');
            console.log(response.data);
            // Handle logout success (e.g., redirect or clear auth state)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Logout failed:', error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <button onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</button>
    );
};


The next login user attempt will success silently because the user session on Google authorization server is still active, having the user feel he wasn't logged out. Plus, an application with oauth2Login already has a /logout endpoint...

@ch4mp How do we invoke the preexisting '/logout' endpoint when we click on the logout button on React?

Look at the code that comes with the OAuth2  BFF article linked in my answer. There's a dedicated section for Logout.
